# Best way to set up a git repo using another git repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab

This one is a little complicated in what I'm trying to ask, so please bear with me.

There exists a public git repo, let's call it 'repoA'. It has a branch 'master'.
I have my own copy of the code (not forked, just downloaded and copied). I have set up my own separate repo using this code, call it 'repoB' (a non-public repo), branch master.

I work on the master branch of the code from repoB, and I have no issue making changes to the code, pulling and pushing to repoB. However, now and then, the person working on repoA may make a change to the code, add new code etc, that I want to have in my master branch from repoB that I work on. I would ideally like to merge the changes into master on repoB from repoA, with any conflicting changes defaulting to preserving my code in repoB if such a conflict occurs.

I was wondering if there was a sensible way of setting this up, and how I would go about doing so. The only work around I could think of was to manually copy repoA's master branch into a separate branch, 'branch2', on repoB everytime repoA is updated, and then merge the 2 branches. However, this sounds very long winded, and I was wondering if there is a smarter way to go about doing this.

Cheers

Comment: Is there any reason for not using a fork? If the two repositories have some commits in common, it is possible to merge branches from remote repositories.

Comment: At present, we wish to make some changes and/or produce data that for the time being are to remain in-house on our gitlab, hence at present I'm hesitant about setting things up in such a way as to potentially make our copy public or able to push changes to the public version of the code 'repoA'. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In that case, I think I would put the focus on the access policies to make sure that nobody accidentally pushes private code to the public repository. Having two different git repositories with the same code looks to me like a misuse of the tool. As a distributed system, git is designed to support this kind of scenarios with multiple remote repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup repoA as upstream and repoB as origin. To prevent pushes to repoA, set push url to a dummy one using `git remote set-url --push upstream dummy_url`

This allows you to pull the code from repoA and push to repoB.
In repoB, leave `master` branch as it is and have an `integrated-master` branch that can be used to merge your changes with the repoA master changes for integrated testing.